# How to bind one key to multiple commands in VSCode

Tags: visual-studio-code, command, key-bindings

I'm trying to make the key `Ctrl+UpArrow` execute both commands 
`cursorUp` and 
`scrollLineUp`.

I was hoping that this would work, but it doesn't:

```jsonc
{
  "key": "ctrl+up",
   "command": ["cursorUp", "scrollLineUp"], // This doesn't work
   "when": "editorTextFocus"
}
```

How do I do that in VSCode?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75808371/how-can-i-run-multiple-commands-with-a-single-vs-code-keybinding-without-an-exte/75808372#75808372

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This is currently not possible, but the corresponding feature request is tracked [here](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/871). However you should take a look to the [macros extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=geddski.macros). It enables you to chain different commands to a single custom command. This custom command then can be bound to a hotkey.
In your case you could add this to your `settings.json`:

```json
"macros": {
    "myCustomCommand": [
        "cursorUp",
        "scrollLineUp"
    ]
}
```

And then add your custom hotkey to the `keybindings.json`:

```json
{
  "key": "ctrl+up",
  "command": "macros.myCustomCommand"
}
```

Comment: Is it possible to create a macro with arguments? I cannot find something like this in the macros extension documentation ...

Comment: Passing Arguments to Commands
Many commands accept arguments, like the "type" command which lets you insert text into the editor. For these cases use an object instead of a string when specifying the command to call in your settings.json:
```
"macros": {
  "addSemicolon": [
    "cursorEnd",
      {"command": "type", "args": {"text": ";"}}
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 7):

There's [a new way](https://dae.me/blog/2603/vs-code-bind-one-key-to-multiple-commands-without-an-extension/) to achieve this without an extension:

1. Run "Tasks: Open User Tasks" command to create or open a user level tasks file.
2. Define commands as separate tasks, like so:

```
{
    "version": "2.0.0",
    "tasks": [
        {
            "label": "ctrlUp1",
            "command": "${command:cursorUp}"
        },
        {
            "label": "ctrlUp2",
            "command": "${command:scrollLineUp}"
        },
        {
            "label": "ctrlUpAll",
            "dependsOrder": "sequence",
            "dependsOn": [
                "ctrlUp1",
                "ctrlUp2"
            ],
            "problemMatcher": []
        }
    ]
}
```

3. In your keybindings.json:

```
{
    "key": "ctrl+up",
    "command": "workbench.action.tasks.runTask",
    "args": "ctrlUpAll",
    "when": "editorTextFocus"
}
```

("ctrlUpNNN" label format chosen for readability, task labels can be anything).

Comment: The configuration within `keybindings.json` semms to be wrong:
You need to use `"command": "workbench.action.tasks.runTask"` and `"args": "ctrlUpAll"` AFAIK. Since this is also documented on the linked page, I will correct the answer.

Comment: Is this an improvement?  3 tasks or 1 macro.  And if you had multiple of these x 3 every time...  I'll use an extension.

Comment: Also wondering if there are any drawbacks to doing with the macros extension

Answer (score 3):

You can use the newly feature `runCommands`

e.g.

```
 {
    "key": "cmd+up",
    "command": "runCommands",
    "args": {
      "commands": ["cursorUp", "scrollLineUp"]
    },
    "when": "editorTextFocus"
  }
```

Reference:
https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/keybindings#_running-multiple-commands