# How can I run multiple commands with a single VS Code keybinding without an extension?

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

Is it possible to run multiple commands from a single keybinding/shortcut, just like a macro operates, in VS Code but without an extension?

I know there are some extensions that can do this but is there a built-in way to do it? Something like:

```
{
  "command": "<run a few commands in sequence>"
  "key": "alt+r",
  "args": [  // some keybinding
    "editor.action.clipboardCopyAction",   // command ids from the Keyboard Shortcuts editors
    "workbench.action.files.newUntitledFile",  
    "editor.action.clipboardPasteAction",
  ]
}
```

And do such options support having a delay between each command?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Available now in the Stable Build v1.77 there is a new built-in command

- `runCommands`      // run one or more commands in sequence

which can run a single command or multiple commands - just like a macro extension can.  See [Test: new command to run multiple commands - runCommands](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/177722).  Here are a couple of example
keybindings (put into your `keybindings.json`):

```json
{
  "command": "runCommands",
  "key": "alt+r",                // whatever keybinding you want
  "args": {
    "commands": [

        "editor.action.clipboardCopyAction",

        "workbench.action.files.newUntitledFile",  
        "editor.action.clipboardPasteAction",

        // prompt for save immediately?
        "workbench.action.files.saveAs"
    ]
  },
  "when": "editorTextFocus"  // can use context keys
}
```

The above would copy the selected text, open a new file, paste the copied text into it and then prompt to save that file.

```json
{
  "command": "runCommands",
  "key": "alt+r",                // whatever keybinding you want
  "args": {
    "commands": [

      "editor.action.copyLinesDownAction",
      "cursorUp",
      "editor.action.addCommentLine",
      "cursorDown"
    ]
  }
}
```

The above would copy the current line, comment it, and add the same line below (uncommented).

```json
{
  "command": "runCommands",
  "key": "alt+r",                // whatever keybinding you want
  "args": {
    "commands": [

      {                                            // use commands that take args
        "command": "editor.actions.findWithArgs",
        "args": {
          "searchString": "trouble",
          // "regexp": true,
        }
      },
      "editor.action.selectAllMatches",
      "editor.action.commentLine"
    ]
  }
}
```

The above finds all matches of `trouble` in the file and comments those lines.

This new `runCommands` command can not currently replace existing macro extensions, including my favorite [multi-command](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ryuta46.multi-command), because some of those have a `delay` or `interval` option to add some time between running the commands.  I have found it necessary to have that ability in some cases and it isn't an option with `runCommands`.

But in most cases with `runCommands` an interval between commands is not needed.

---

I have filed an issue suggesting that this "macro" operate in an atomic way - that is, when undoing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd> it, all the steps/commands should be undone at once, not just one command at a time.  Please upvote the github issue if would like to see that behaviour: [Consider making runCommands "atomic"](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/177908)

---

For extension developers, the `runCommands` command can be run like this:

```js
const commandArray =  [
  "editor.action.copyLinesDownAction",
  "cursorUp",
  "editor.action.addCommentLine",
  "cursorDown"
];

await vscode.commands.executeCommand('runCommands', { commands: commandArray });
```

or to use commands which take arguments:

```js
const commandArray = [
  { 
    "command": "workbench.action.files.newUntitledFile",
      "args": {
        "languageId": "typescript",
       }
  },
  {
    "command": "type",
      "args": {
        "text": "/* add some text here */"
      }
  }
];

await vscode.commands.executeCommand('runCommands', { commands: commandArray });
```